# File is read only in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, readonly

I worked on my projects for a while and restored intellij IDE back to default. My files are now read only, how do I make them editable again?I have not been able to do so. Im new and stuck please help.

Comment: Can you edit the files with other programs?

Comment: There is a [lock symbol in the bottom of the toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47YFM.png). Is the lock open or closed? What happens if you click on the lock?

Comment: Open the file with Notepad++, then Edit / Clear read-only flag.

Comment: I dont have other programs only intellij, the lock is open and I can do ne projects but not the previous ones.